# If I want to stream tweet into BigQuery, which is the best way?

Tags: python, twitter, google-cloud-platform, stream, google-bigquery

I want to do some tweet analytics and show real time result to customer. The first step is stream tweet into BigQuery. I found some method, cloud pub/sub, app engine, compute engine etc. How to choose? Is there any better ways to do that?

Comment: Depends on your trigger and the processing duration (or the volume of tweet to stream in one execution). Can you add more detail on your process ?

Comment: Consider Pub/Sub -> Dataflow -> BigQuery.

Comment: @guillaume blaguiere:The trigger is user's keyword which means if use input one keyword I will send tweet s related to that keyword and sentiment analysis for every tweet. In training time, the volume of tweets maybe ten or hundred million. In interactive time, I hope the system can collect last day's tweets, but I haven't thought it through how many tweets are better.

Answer (score 4):

I would:

- Push tweet into Pub/Sub. Encode it as a full [{row:""}]
- Click on the Pub/Sub button "stream to BigQuery" (make sure to have an existing table with a column called "row").
- Parse the "" inside BigQuery into a full fledged table.

Comment: My question of volume was for finding the best solution. In this solution, you have a dataflow always running which stream pubsub data into bigquery. So, you have always at least 1 VM up. However, if the flow is sparse, you can consider to trigger a Cloud Function on the same pubsub event and to stream write into bigquery programmatically. The second advantage, you can preprocess the tweet before streaming it. Thus you save BigQuery (post)processing. The right tool for the right job and the right volume !